# Angular UI date-picker bind on demand

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui, ondemand

[http://jsfiddle.net/shykwoh3/2/]

```
<span class="input-group">
        <input type="text"
            class="form-control"
            ng-model="hole.date"  
        />
        <!-- 
            datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd"
            show-button-bar="false"
            is-open="opened" 
        -->

        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button"
                class="btn btn-default"
                ng-click="showDatePicker();">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
            </button>
        </span>
    </span>
```

I am trying to create a dynamic/on-demand date picker.

Explenation: I would like to have a single directive or controller function that can call or show a date picker but binding has to happen only on the fields which calander icons were clicked. I.E. It should not bind these input fields to a date picker etc. until the icon is clicked, the reson being, if I have lets say 1000 dates like these on a page, the page loads very slowly because of the date picker popup binding that is binded on page load.

The default popup datepicker works something like this:

Bootstrap.UI: angular-ui.github.io (Scroll down to Datepicker (ui.bootstrap.datepicker))

If anyone understands my problem and what I am trying to achieve please help me out: Something like Modal Date Picker but I don't want a Modal. The date picker should seem to work exactly like the popup date picker of http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ but the binding should not happen on page load, but on click only

Comment: use ng-if, show datepicker on click else input

Comment: I still couldn't get this to work

Comment: can you setup a plunker